# Why is x86_64 assembly to execve "/bin/bash" segfaulting?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, disassembly

I've been relearning and writing some assembly code, very basic stuff for starters. I'm on running Ubuntu on x86_64, but the tutorials I'm following along with were done on 32-bit x86.

I've included the short assembly program below, which assembles and links fine, but segfaults when running it. I'm betting my error is some mixup/confusion with respect to the lines between 32 and 64 bit instructions and memory usage. For example, I am using `movq` instructions on all the `r**` registers (x86_64 version of 32 bit registers from what I've gathered) - but perhaps that is in error.

I'd really appreciate it if someone is able to explain the problem here, I feel like if I better understood the cause it would really help avoid these types of problems in the future.

```
 .data
Bash:
    .asciz "/bin/bash"
Null1:
    .int 0
AddrToBash:
    .int 0
Null2:
    .int 0

.text
.globl _start

_start:
movq $Bash, AddrToBash
movq $59, %rax
movq $Bash, %rbx
movq $AddrToBash, %rcx
movq $Null2, %rdx
syscall 

Exit:
movq $60, %rbx
movq $1, %rax
syscall
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Syscall arguments are in `%rsi`, `%rdi`, `%rdx`. See [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64).
2. `.int 0` is too short, should be `.quad 0` in all three places.

Comment: I figured int was too short there, so I blindly tried 'long' - none of my searching yielded a suggestion to use .quad, thanks! Also, your reference to the calling conventions did the trick - thanks so much.

Comment: I actually failed to recall the *name* of `.quad` directive (was it `.qword` or something?). `gcc -S` helps in such cases.